# ArcGIS for Desktop Concurrent Use

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, arcgis-license-manager

For ArcGIS for Desktop (Concurrent) users how do you add multiple computers so that they can also use ArcGIS for Desktop as well? Is it through the License Manager, ArcGIS Administrator, or is there some other way of establishing a network connection?

Any help or suggestions would be beneficial.

Thanks.

Comment: You just install arcgis on the computers you need it one (can be 10 or 100) but they point to the License Server over a network. Enter that name on the client http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/install-guides/license-manager/10.1/index.html#/Client_machine_setup_using_the_ArcGIS_Administrator/007900000006000000/

Answer (score 2):

The Licence Manager is installed somewhere on the local network and has installed the pool of licences that you have access to.  The ArcGIS Administrator application sits on each client desktop and you enter the name of the Licence Manager in there.  Then when you start ArcGIS Desktop, it will check out a licence from the Licence Manager pool, and check it back in when you close ArcGIS Desktop.  You can do this on as many computers as you like on your local network, but obviously the number of licences in the pool will dictate how many ArcGIS Desktop clients you can have open at the same time.

Comment: What defines a 'local network'? The computer with the License Manager my ArcGIS Administrator checks with is thousands of miles away...

Answer (score 1):

Use the "ArcGIS Administrator": Start > Programs > ArcGIS > ArcGIS Administrator.... Specify the name (computer name or IP address of the computer on the network that is running the ArcGIS License Server)... in my case, that is a server by the name of 'dnrutoly111'. If your local machine is configured as the ArcGIS License Server, then you would specify the name/IP address of your local machine.

[image]